remove transform animation in highcharts range-selector
I'm currently using highcharts in reactjs to display the candle stick chart. The candle stick chart is plotted in second-to-second basis to display the stock price. I'm using the state hooks to set the data hence it triggers the re-render. But whenever the re-render, the range-selector will have a transform animation from left to right. So every second re-render the transform is applied makes it unviewable and unwanted behavior. After walking through the api documentation from highcharts https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector, i don't see anything regarding removing the transform animation. So I try to apply
.highcharts-range-selector-group,
.highcharts-range-selector-buttons {
  transform: none !important;
  transition: none !important;
  animation: none !important;
}

to the css and it works only for the first render, and same transform animation applied again.
Highcharts range selector element:
<g class="highcharts-range-selector-group" data-z-index="7" transform="translate(730,0)">
    <g class="highcharts-range-selector-buttons" transform="translate(0,10)">
        <g class="highcharts-label" transform="translate(10,0)">
            <text x="0" data-z-index="1" y="15.5" style="color: rgb(102, 102, 102); font-size: 0.8em; fill: rgb(102, 102, 102);">Zoom</text>
        </g>
        <g class="highcharts-no-tooltip highcharts-button highcharts-button-normal" data-z-index="7" transform="translate(48,0)" style="cursor: pointer;">
            <rect fill="gray" class="highcharts-button-box" x="0" y="0" width="32" height="22" rx="2" ry="2" stroke="white" stroke-width="0"></rect>
            <text x="3.4267168045043945" data-z-index="1" y="15.5" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-size: 0.8em; font-weight: normal; fill: rgb(51, 51, 51);">30m</text>
        </g>
        <g class="highcharts-no-tooltip highcharts-button highcharts-button-pressed" data-z-index="7" transform="translate(85,0)" style="cursor: pointer;">
            <rect fill="#e6e9ff" class="highcharts-button-box" x="0" y="0" width="32" height="22" rx="2" ry="2" stroke="white" stroke-width="0"></rect>
            <text x="8.528409481048584" data-z-index="1" y="15.5" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 0.8em; font-weight: bold; fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);">1h</text>
        </g>
        <g class="highcharts-no-tooltip highcharts-button highcharts-button-normal" data-z-index="7" transform="translate(122,0)" style="cursor: pointer;">
            <rect fill="gray" class="highcharts-button-box" x="0" y="0" width="32" height="22" rx="2" ry="2" stroke="white" stroke-width="0"></rect>
            <text x="8.428977489471436" data-z-index="1" y="15.5" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-size: 0.8em; font-weight: normal; fill: rgb(51, 51, 51);">All</text>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>

